# Convert Statement to Crystal Reports SQL Expression

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a SQL command that works great in SQL Server. Here's the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
(
  SELECT COUNT(LINENUM)
  FROM OEORDD D1
  WHERE D1.ORDUNIQ = OEORDD.ORDUNIQ
)
  - (SELECT COUNT(LINENUM)
  FROM OEORDD D1
  WHERE D1.ORDUNIQ = OEORDD.ORDUNIQ
  AND D1.LINENUM > OEORDD.LINENUM)
FROM OEORDD
ORDER BY ORDUNIQ, LINENUM
```

The query looks at the total lines on an order, then looks at the current "LINENUM" field. With the value of the LINENUM field, it looks to see how many lines have a greater LINENUM value on the order and subtracts it from the number of lines on an order to get the correct Line number.

When I try to add it as a SQL expression in version 14.0.2.364 as follows:

```
(
  ( 
    SELECT COUNT("OEORDD"."LINENUM")
    FROM "OEORDD" "D1"
    WHERE "D1"."ORDUNIQ" = "OEORDD"."ORDUNIQ"
  )
    - (SELECT COUNT("OEORDD"."LINENUM")
    FROM "OEORDD" "D1"
    WHERE "D1"."ORDUNIQ" = "OEORDD"."ORDUNIQ"
    AND "D1"."LINENUM" > "OEORDD"."LINENUM"
  )
)
```

I get the error "Column 'SAMDB.dbo.OEORDD.ORDUNIQ' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I try to add GROUP BY "OEORDD"."ORDUNIQ" at the end, I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. I've tried adding "FROM OEORDD" at the end of query and it errors out on the word "FROM". I have the correct tables linked in the Database Expert.

**EDIT --------------**

I was able to get the first query working by getting rid of the alias, it's as follows:

```
  (
    SELECT COUNT(LINENUM) 
    FROM OEORDD 
    WHERE OEORDH.ORDUNIQ=OEORDD.ORDUNIQ)
  )
```

However, I believe I need to use the alias in the second query to compare line numbers. I'm still stuck on that one.

Comment: instead of creating a single sql expression.. create two and perform minus operation in crystal report design

Comment: Thank you so much @Siva I will try as soon as I get back on Monday.

Comment: @Siva I tried to separate each expression into its own but I get the error "The multi-part identifier "OEORDD.ORDUNIQ" could not be bound".

Comment: @Siva I was able to get the first query working, see my above post. I'm still stuck on the second query.

Comment: I don't see any use of alias in second query as formula is different... try without alias